# Hide element in foreach loop if other element is present

Tags: php, foreach

I have a list of colors in `$colors` and want to remove certain colors if another color is present in the loop.

For example: If the color `blue` is part of the loop, I want to remove the color `dark-blue` from the list.

I tried to check if the color `blue` is in the array. But I'm not sure how and how I can ignore it after that in the foreach loop.

This is my current code:

```
<?php 
$colors     = $product->get_attribute('colors');
if( strpos($colors, 'blue') !== false ) :
    $has_blue = true;
else :
    $has_blue = false;
endif;

foreach ( $colors as $color ) : 

// content

endforeach;
?>
```

I think my approach isn't the best practice method because I need to add a `if/else` statement for every color.

Is there a better way to do this?

Here's the array of `$colors` (one item):

```
array(6) {
    [0]=>
    object(WP_Term)#27294 (10) {
    ["term_id"]=>
    int(85)
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Blue"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(5) "blue"
    ["term_group"]=>
    int(0)
    ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
    int(85)
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(7) "color"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["parent"]=>
    int(0)
    ["count"]=>
    int(720)
    ["filter"]=>
    string(3) "raw"
}
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of $colors?

Comment: sure, added one array item to my question

Comment: Why not use `array_filter` to remove all items with another color, and check whether that list is empty or not?

Comment: @NicoHaase not sure how. There could be an item with only `dark blue`. In this case I don't want to remove it from the list. Only if `blue` is present.

Comment: Do you mean if I got a string "blue", any element's name contains "blue" (or "Blue") should be removed?

Comment: Yeah, then check for that. A equality check is not that hard to write (`if($string === 'blue')`)

Comment: @shingo no, I can't say that for sure.

Comment: @NicoHaase I try to understand what you suggest :-) give me a minute

Answer (score 1):

You are checking it the wrong way. There are still some things missing in your question. First of all what is the data type of this?
`$colors     = $product->get_attribute('colors');`
Is it an array? Or some data loop? Data loops are pretty much same as array. Is it a multidimensional array? If not then use  `in_array()` function to check for the color.
In this way you can deduct the use of foreach. If it is a multidimensional array then you have put the if conditionals inside foreach loop like this:

```
foreach ( $colors as $color ) : 

if( strpos($color, 'blue') !== false ) :
    $has_blue = true;
else :
    $has_blue = false;
endif;

endforeach;
```

If you need anything else please elaborate your question some more.

Comment: Thanks! I tried `in_array` before with no luck. But maybe I've done it wrong because it's an array. I added the first array item to my question.

Comment: It is mixed with object. How about you access your data with object->method() way. Then see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [`FilterIterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.filteriterator.php). And because name in your example is capitailized I use stripos instead of strpos.

```
class ColorFilter extends FilterIterator
{
    private $_filter;
    
    public function __construct($colors, $filter)
    {
        parent::__construct(new ArrayIterator($colors));
        $this->_filter = $filter;
    }
    
    public function accept()
    {
        $color = $this->getInnerIterator()->current();
        return stripos($color->name, $this->_filter) === false;
    }
}

foreach(new ColorFilter($colors, 'blue') as $filted_color)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can filter the colors dynamically like this:

```
$colors_3 = [
    0 => (object) [
        "name" => "Blue",
    ],
    1 => (object) [
        "name" => "Dark Blue",
    ],
    2 => (object) [
        "name" => "Red",
    ],
    3 => (object) [
        "name" => "Dark Red",
    ],
    4 => (object) [
        "name" => "Dark Orange",
    ],
    5 => (object) [
        "name" => "Purple",
    ],
];

function filter_colors($colors)
{
    $filter_me = [];
    $filtered_colors = [];

    foreach ($colors as $color) {
        $parts = explode(" ", $color->name);
        if (count($parts) == 1) {
            $filter_me[] = $color->name;
        }
    }

    foreach ($colors as $color) {
        $parts = explode(" ", $color->name);
        foreach ($parts as $part) {
            if (in_array($part, $filter_me)) {
                if (count($parts) == 1) {
                    break;
                }

                continue 2;
            }
        }

        $filtered_colors[] = $color;
    }

    return $filtered_colors;
}

print_r(filter_colors($colors_3);
```

We get a filtered array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Blue
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Red
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Dark Orange
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Purple
        )

)
```

If this doesn't work for some reason with the real data please update your question to include more test data.